# Getting "on" when accessing radio buttons values with JQuery and JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twig

I'm trying to access radio buttons values but all I get is "on".
I've tried JQuery and JS and both give me this result.
My inputs has a span inside of it, When I get the val() of the input it gives me "on".
When trying to access the span inside of the input it wont show anything.

My code:

```
            <ul id="sportCourtsRow" tabindex=44>
                <div id="sportCourtsRowIn" style="margin-left: 31vw; margin-top: 0.8vh;">
                    {% for c in courtsB %}
                        {% if loop.index == 1 %}
                            <li class="courtsItem" style="position: relative;">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="sportCourts" class="sportCourts" checked="checked"><span id="courtsItem{{c}}" class="sportsCourtsTxt">{{c}}</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>

                        {% else %}
                            <li class="courtsItem" style="position: relative;">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="sportCourts" class="sportCourts"><span id="courtsItem{{c}}" class="sportsCourtsTxt">{{c}}</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </ul>

           <script>
            window.onload = function() {
            var courts = $('input[name="sportCourts"]').each(function(){
                document.getElementById("monthTxt").innerHTML += $(this).val();//test if working
            });
            });
           </script>



  #sportCourtsRow
  {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 28vh;
    height: 6vh;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 15vw;
    background: transparent;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    text-indent: -5vw;
  }


  #sportCourtsRow::-webkit-scrollbar 
  {
    display: none;
  }
  .sportsCourtsTxt
  {
    font-family: 'alef';
    font-size: 2.75vh;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 1vh;
    margin-right: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: Input elements don’t have an ‘inside’. Are you looking for the clicked attribute?

Comment: The `<span>`s are not _inside_ of the `<input>`s; `<input>`s don’t have content. Your `<input>`s also don’t have a `value`, so I’m not sure why you expect `.val` to return some unrelated text content of a different element.

Comment: Ohh yeah i forget adding values. so stupid. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of your radio buttons is correct. Use

```
$(this).siblings()[0].innerText;
```

instead of

```
$(this).val();
```

Comment: Logic doesn't make sense. The `each` is iterating the radios. There are no `siblings('input')`

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for pointing it out. It was a typo on my part https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: Still not making sense. The sibling of each radio is a span that has no `value`

Comment: @charlietfl you are correct. Maybe I'm dizzy today. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It Turns out that I have forgotten to add values to my inputs.
So that solved it.
There is another solution that works which Lajos Arpad pointed out.
Thanks to everybody here helping!